# Trying to create function but getting incompatible data type when setting it to actual return type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a simple function in Snowflake under my schema. All it does is query a table.

Something to the effect of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYNEWFUNCTION (DATE_KEY_INPUT INT) 
RETURNS TABLE (COLUMN1 date, COLUMN2 int, COLUMN3 varchar(255) )

as '

SELECT 
COLUMN1
,COLUMN2
,COLUMN3
FROM "TABLE"."DBO"."TABLENAME" 
where column1 = date_key_input
';
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`Declared return type 'VARCHAR(255)' for column 'COLUMN3' is incompatible with actual return type 'VARCHAR(255)'`

I'm lost... its not compatible with the actual data type? What am I missing here...?

The data type from the original table is varchar(255), in the function I've set it to varchar(255) - why is it rejecting?

Also I should note the source is a view not a table, so concretely, I'm trying to create a function which creates a table from a view...

Comment: Can you share with us the results of `get_ddl` (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html) for the table?

Comment: Sorry new to all of this - I tried running ```select GET_DDL('view', 'Database.Schema.Table')``` but I'm getting the following error ```SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.```

Comment: Just to be sure - did you try it like that, or with the actual name of your view/table? Note that the first argument should reflect if the second is a view or a table

Comment: I tried it just like that, ```'Database.Schema.Table'``` is actually a view in our environment. So the naming convention can be ignored in this case which is denoting "table".

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple things going on in your example:

- the first issue was the returns clause defining the length of the varchar, you won't need the length
- the second was the input parameter/argument not having the right datatype, or
  the query was not constructed correctly (col1 was date, col2 was int).

Working example below.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 date, col2 integer, col3 varchar(255));
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (current_date(), 1, 'Hello World'),  (current_date(), 2, 'Goodbye');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYNEWFUNCTION (x integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (col1 date, col2 integer, col3 varchar)
as
$$
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM my_table 
where col2 = x
$$
;

SELECT * from TABLE(MYNEWFUNCTION(1));
```

Comment: Thank you Rich for the input, I changed everything you mentioned, 1. removing the 255 from the varchar length and simply using varchar,   and now i'm getting the error ```Declared return type 'VARCHAR(16777216)' for column 'COLUMN3' is incompatible with actual return type 'VARCHAR(255)``` I also fixed the parameter arugment datatype. The column3 from the original view has the following details if it matters ```VARCHAR(255) COLLATE 'en-ci-rtrim'```

Comment: Did you change it in the code - the section "returns table ...." ?
Does the above example work for you, and if so can you check the differences between yours and the example?

Answer (score 0):

Collation Limitations in Snowflake:

At present Collation and UDFs (user-defined functions) do not always work together. For example, you cannot return a collated string value from a UDF; the server complains that the actual return type is incompatible with the declared return type. You also cannot pass a collated string value to a UDF.

Reference :https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html